# Reg Ex won't find match with preceding white space

Tags: regex

I'm trying to grab the fields that either have dashed or sometimes numbers (it's from a wrapped calendar).  It won't grab a group if a number follows a `--`. This is the regular expression that I'm using:

```
(-{2}\s|\s[0-9]{1,2}\s|\s[0-9]{1,2}){7}
```

This is my input:

```
 Base : DEN CA01FO01 99 -- -- -- -- -- -- 

 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

 -- 11 -- -- -- -- -- 

 11 11 11 11 11 11 --

TU 5368 DEN-BIL 0750 0922 132 136 30 RJU -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Here are the [results](https://regex101.com/r/rnUmJT/1).

It should have grabbed the group `-- 11 -- -- -- -- --` but it didn't. It's almost as if since it matched `--\s` that it used that `\s` and won't match `\s11`.

Comment: What is the expected result? What do you expect the regex to match?

Comment: This: '-{2}\s' will match the space - now there's no space to match before number. Try to make one of the spaces optional ( put a question mark '?' after it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match 7 times either 1 or 2 digits or 2 dashes which can also consists of only digits or only pairs of dashes, you could make use of an alternation and lookarounds (if supported).

First match either 1-2 digits or `--`. Then repeat 6 times matching a whitespace char followed by matching 1-2 digits or `--`

```
(?<!\S)(?:[0-9]{1,2}|--)(?:\s(?:[0-9]{1,2}|--)){6}(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rsdvAU/1)

If lookaronds are not supported, you could make use of a capturing group:

```
(?:^|\s)((?:[0-9]{1,2}|--)(?:\s(?:[0-9]{1,2}|--)){6})(?:$|\s)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BE7bTP/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your regex to:

```
(\s(--|\d{1,2})){7}
```

and will get your desired output:

> ```
>  99 -- -- -- -- -- --
>  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>  -- 11 -- -- -- -- --
>  11 11 11 11 11 11 --
>  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> ```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iM64U4/3/)